# Moving OpenVPN client files from Users directory in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, openvpn

I've been using the OpenVPN client in Windows 7 and it leaves two files in my `Users` directory. One is a log file and one is a json file. If I move them they are re-created.

Does anyone know a way to change the path where these files are saved? The files are `openvpn-connect.json` and `ovpntray.log`.